# Expected value of $f(r)$ conditional on $r$

Tags: independence, conditional-expectation

I have two independent variables $v^M$ and $v^K$. Define their ratio $r= \frac{v^K}{v^M}$. Define the function $f(r) = \mathbb{E}(v^M \mid r)$. I have to show that $f$ is a non-increasing function. We clearly have that $\mathrm{Cov}(v^M, v^K) =0$. Now given that $r = \frac{v^K}{v^M}$, we also have $\mathrm{Cov}(v^M, rv^M) =0$. By the Law of Total Covariance we can rewrite
$$
 \mathrm{Cov}(v^M, rv^M)  = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathrm{Cov}(v^M, rv^M \mid r)\right] + \mathrm{Cov} \left( \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(v^M \mid r)}_{f(r)}, \mathbb{E}\left( rv^M \mid r\right) \right)
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ r \mathrm{Cov}(v^M, v^M \mid r)\right] + \mathrm{Cov} \left( f(r), r f(r)\right)
$$
$$
 \mathbb{E}\left[ r \mathrm{Var}(v^M \mid r)\right] + \mathrm{Cov} \left( f(r), r f(r)\right) =0.
$$
Now given that the first term is always positive, the second must be negative so that their sum is zero. We conclude that $\mathrm{Cov} \left( f(r), r f(r)\right) \leq 0$. As $r$ increases, it must therefore be true that $f(r)$ decreases. Hence, $f(r)$ is non-increasing, as desired.

Now, my question is the following: can $f$ be constant in $r$? If it is $\mathrm{Cov} \left( f(r), r f(r)\right)=0$, so in order to get $\mathrm{Cov}(v^M, rv^M)=0$ it must be the case that the first term, $ \mathbb{E}\left[ r \mathrm{Var}(v^M \mid r)\right]$ is zero as well. My understanding however is that if $f(r)$ is contant, i.e. $r$ gives no information on $v^M$, it's "the opposite" of saying that the variance of $v^M$ given $r$ is $0$. Should I therefore conclude that $f(r)$ is strictly decreasing, rather than simply non-increasing?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Given $r$, $v^K$ and $v^M$ cannot be independent, in fact, given $r$, $v^K = rv^M$, so the conditional correlation equals 1.

Comment: I am not looking at the correlation between $v^K$ and $v^M$ conditional on r: I am starting from the unconditional between $v^K$ and $v^M$ (which is 0 because by assumption they are independent) and then replacing $v^K$ with $rv^M$, before applying the law of total covariance

Comment: Since $v^M = v^K/r$, $\mathbb{E}(v^M | r) = (\mathbb{E}v^K) / r$, which is clearly nonincreasing in $r$ if $\mathbb{E}v^K \geq 0$.  If $\mathbb{E}v^K = 0$, then $f$ is constant in $r$, so you can't conclude it's strictly decreasing.

Comment: "Now given that the first term is always positive" are you sure $r>0$? because if not then first term is not always positive

Comment: Yes $r >0$ because $v^K$ and $v^M$ are both supported on intervals in $\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: @jbowman I am not sure I understand what you mean: $\mathbb{E}(v^M \mid r = \frac{1}{r} \mathbb{E}(v^K \mid r$ and it's not obvious that this is non-decreasing in $r$: for a given $v^M$, when $r$ increases there is a higher $v^K$!

Comment: You aren't being asked to solve for a given $v^M$, but for a given $r$...  $v^M$ is random and so is $v^K$, it's just that $v^M = v^K/r$, so $v^M$ is obviously nonincreasing in $r$, which of course means the expectation is too.